# Docker "failed to resolve scoped path" using auto generated Dockerfile made by Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, docker, visual-studio-2022

Below is an auto generated Dockerfile that Visual studio 2022 created.  I can debug the application in Docker but I can't create a Docker Image.  Every time I try I get the error copied at the bottom saying it can't copy over the files.  Are the relative paths incorrect?

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

#Depending on the operating system of the host machines(s) that will build or run the containers, the image specified in the FROM statement may need to be changed.
#For more information, please see https://aka.ms/containercompat

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src


COPY ["ServicePM/ServicePM.csproj", "ServicePM/"]
COPY ["../Common/MyCompany.Common/MyCompany.Common.csproj", "../Common/MyCompany.Common/"]
COPY ["../Common/MyCompany.Common.Utilities/MyCompany.Common.Utilities.csproj", "../Common/MyCompany.Common.Utilities/"]
COPY ["../BcEventHarvest/MyCompany.PartitionUpdater/MyCompany.PartitionUpdater.csproj", "../BcEventHarvest/MyCompany.PartitionUpdater/"]
COPY ["../Common/MyCompany.Data2/MyCompany.Data2.csproj", "../Common/MyCompany.Data2/"]
COPY ["../Common/MyCompany.EventCache/MyCompany.EventCache/MyCompany.EventCache.csproj", "../Common/MyCompany.EventCache/MyCompany.EventCache/"]
COPY ["../Common/MyCompany.CloudStorage/MyCompany.CloudStorage.csproj", "../Common/MyCompany.CloudStorage/"]
COPY ["../Common/Providers/CSProfiler/MyCompany.Common.Providers.CSProfiler.csproj", "../Common/Providers/CSProfiler/"]
COPY ["../Common/MyCompany.EventDataMesh/MyCompany.EventDataMesh.csproj", "../Common/MyCompany.EventDataMesh/"]
COPY ["../BcEventHarvest/BcEventHarvest/BcEventHarvest.csproj", "../BcEventHarvest/BcEventHarvest/"]
COPY ["../Common/Providers/DownloadManagement/MyCompany.Common.Providers.DownloadManagement.csproj", "../Common/Providers/DownloadManagement/"]
COPY ["../Common/Providers/ImageManagement/MyCompany.Common.Providers.ImageManagement.csproj", "../Common/Providers/ImageManagement/"]
COPY ["../Common/Providers/WebDriver/MyCompany.Common.Providers.WebDriver.csproj", "../Common/Providers/WebDriver/"]
COPY ["../BcEventHarvest/MyCompany.FileCache/MyCompany.FileCache.csproj", "../BcEventHarvest/MyCompany.FileCache/"]
COPY ["../Common/MyCompany.Data/MyCompany.Data.csproj", "../Common/MyCompany.Data/"]
RUN dotnet restore "ServicePM/ServicePM.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ServicePM"
RUN dotnet build "ServicePM.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ServicePM.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ServicePM.dll"]
```

And here is the error

````
15>COPY failed: failed to resolve scoped path ..\Common\CitySpark.Common\CitySpark.Common.csproj (): evalSymlinksInScope: \\?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\Common\CitySpark.Common\CitySpark.Common.csproj is not in \\?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\docker-builder739514268. Possible cause is a forbidden path outside the build context
15>C:\dev\MyCompany\PartitionManager\ServicePM\Dockerfile : error CTC1014: Docker command failed with exit code 1.
15>C:\dev\MyCompany\PartitionManager\ServicePM\Dockerfile : error CTC1014: COPY failed: failed to resolve scoped path ..\Common\MyCompany.Common\MyCompany.Common.csproj (): evalSymlinksInScope: \\?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\Common\MyCompany.Common\MyCompany.Common.csproj is not in \\?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\docker-builder739514268. Possible cause is a forbidden path outside the build context
15>Done building project "ServicePM.csproj" -- FAILED.
========== Rebuild All: 14 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========```
````

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer on the team that's responsible for Docker support in Visual Studio.

It looks like your project has some dependencies that are in a higher folder than the solution file for your project, which is a scenario that isn't currently supported. When building a Dockerfile, a context folder must be specified that is used to resolve references to files or folders being copied into the generated image. Any paths above this context folder (starting with a .., for example) can't be resolved. For Visual Studio, we've settled on using the folder containing the open solution file (.sln) as the build context path.

With docker build, it's important not to accidentally use to high level of a context folder for builds as a common pattern in Dockerfiles is to copy all files and folders under the context into the image with a "COPY . ." command. This means we can't just set the build context to the highest folder that contains all the referenced projects as we might accidentally end up copying files unrelated to the given solution (or even system files) into the new Docker image.

We'll add some additional checks to our Docker scaffolding logic in a future release to more proactively catch this scenario and provide a helpful error message rather than scaffolding a broken Dockerfile.

For this project, you'd need to move your solution file to a parent folder that contains the ServicePM project as well as all referenced projects. Unfortunately, if the parent folder contains other unrelated projects/files, additional Dockerfile customization may be required to avoid copying all those assets into your Dockerfile. In general, the more complex the folder structure of a given soluton/projects, the more likely it is that the Dockerfile created by Visual Studio will need to be customized to suit the projects particular layout.

Comment: It makes sense that you don't want to pick too high of a context folder and then copy everything beneath that folder but if the solution references each project file can't you pick a higher context folder and then elect to just copy the contents from each project folder in the solution?